# Two arrays have slightly different array size with same size disks/partitions, why?

Tags: raid, mdadm, software-raid

I created a software RAID 5 array one year ago using mdadm v3.2.x which shipped from CentOS 6.3, after few months, I moved/assembled the array to/in Fedora 19 (now Fedora 20).

It had three 3TB disks (Seagate [ST3000DM001](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/desktop-hard-drives/desktop-hdd/?sku=ST3000DM001)) in it, and it's almost full, so I added 2 disks and grow the array to 4 disks + 1 hot spare disk. Now it's size is **8383.55 GiB**.

```
# mdadm -D /dev/md127 
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 11 17:56:18 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 8790792192 (8383.55 GiB 9001.77 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930264064 (2794.52 GiB 3000.59 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Mar 25 11:04:15 2014
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : RecordBackup01:127  (local to host RecordBackup01)
           UUID : dfd3bbe7:4b0231fe:9007bc4a:e106acac
         Events : 7264

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       3       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       5       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1

       4       8       65        -      spare   /dev/sde1
```

Then I created another array (RAID 6) using mdadm v3.3 (which shipped from Fedora 20) with 5 3TB disks (Toshiba [DT01ACA300](http://storage.toshiba.eu/cms/en/hdd/computing/product_detail.jsp?productid=447)), but it's size is **8383.18 GiB**, which is slightly smaller than 8383.55 GiB.

```
# mdadm -D /dev/md127 
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 21 18:12:00 2014
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 8790402048 (8383.18 GiB 9001.37 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930134016 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Tue Mar 25 11:18:51 2014
          State : active 
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : RecordBackup02:127  (local to host RecordBackup02)
           UUID : 923c9658:12739258:506fc8b0:f8c5edf3
         Events : 8172

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       3       8       65        3      active sync   /dev/sde1
       4       8       81        4      active sync   /dev/sdf1
```

The partition size of each disk in the two arrays are identical (all partitions have 5860531087 logical sectors, see the following partition information), so why the array size are different? Is it caused by different mdadm version or different array level or something else?

### Array 1 (RAID 5) disks/partitions information

```
# LANG=en parted /dev/sdb "unit s print all"                                                                                        
Model: ATA ST3000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 5860533168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  5860533134s  5860531087s               pri


Model: ATA ST3000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 5860533168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  5860533134s  5860531087s  ext4         primary


Model: ATA ST3000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 5860533168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  5860533134s  5860531087s  ext4         primary


Model: ATA ST3000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 5860533168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  5860533134s  5860531087s               primary


Model: ATA ST3000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdf: 5860533168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  5860533134s  5860531087s               primary




Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md127: 17581584384s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End           Size          File system  Flags
 1      0s     17581584383s  17581584384s  xfs
```

### Array 2 (RAID 6) disks/partitions information

```
# LANG=en parted /dev/sdb "unit s print all"
Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 5860533168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  5860533134s  5860531087s               primary


Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 5860533168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  5860533134s  5860531087s               primary


Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 5860533168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  5860533134s  5860531087s               primary


Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 5860533168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  5860533134s  5860531087s               primary


Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdf: 5860533168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  5860533134s  5860531087s               primary






Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md127: 17580804096s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End           Size          File system  Flags
 1      0s     17580804095s  17580804096s  xfs
```

Comment: You did a good job forcing all the disk/partitions to be the same size. Still I would not be surprise to found out that RAID6 has a slightly bigger overhead than RAID5.

Comment: @Ouki, you mean the metadata size overhead, or the performance overhead?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious difference is:

```
Intent Bitmap : Internal
```

Is it possible that the mdadm versions have different defaults for whether or not the intent bitmap is enabled?

As I understand it, the internal intent bitmap uses a portion of the disks to store what it is about to write, so it doesn't need to validate every block, when it rebuilds should you replace a failed disk.

Try explicitly creating your RAID with `mdadm --bitmap=none ...` or `mdadm --bitmap=internal ...`

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Write-intent_bitmap

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the write intent bitmap caused the difference, highly doubt it (because it will not take many spaces). I asked same question in linux.raid mailing list, **Mikael Abrahamsson** guess it's because of different data offset, which I believe it (but still no explanation for it). http://www.spinics.net/lists/raid/msg46175.html

Answer (score -1):

You are asking about size ... so yes size overhead. My best guess is that the extra parity requires some sort of extra index or something (without knowing much of the inside of RAID6). We are talking about 370+ MB for a 8.3 TB  ... this is less than 0.005% of the total space!

Comment: I just did a quick RAID creation test on loop devices in CentOS 6.5 (mdadm v3.2.x) and Fedora 20 (mdadm v3.3), found out that **it's not the size overhead of RAID 6**. Size of RAID 5 & RAID 6 are identical in same OS, but they are different between CentOS and Fedora. Test script: `MAKEDEV /dev/loop; truncate -s 10M hdd5{1..5} hdd6{1..5}; for hdd in {1..5}; do losetup /dev/loop5$hdd hdd5$hdd; losetup /dev/loop6$hdd hdd6$hdd; done; mdadm -C /dev/md5 -l 5 -n 4 -x 1 /dev/loop5{1..5}; mdadm -C /dev/md6 -l 6 -n 5 /dev/loop6{1..5}; mdadm -D /dev/md5; mdadm -D /dev/md6`

Comment: Doubtful it is about the OS itself. I would be more about some overhead related to the `mdadm` versions.

Comment: The extra parity of RAID 6 requires exactly one full drive of space, no more, no less.